# Android Execute Multiple AsyncTask Parallely

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

Hello All I am a bit confuse about execute multiple asynctask parallely in Android

Before Donut it was just single processing means we can execute only one task at a time but later it has changed and we can execute multiple asynctask parallely, in that case there was also limit to execute the multiple asynctask that we can execute only 138 Async Task thread at a time other wise it will through exception but later of honeycomb it has changed and we can execute 5 asynctask at a time and 10 can be in waiting queue, but if we execute more than 15 asynctask at a time means if I will execute 16 task at a time then it will execute 6 task parallelly and 10 will be in queue, it means there will be atleast 10 task in waiting queue to wait for working thread to get finish, and also later in Kitkat it has been changes and it first get the number of processor running currently in Vm and according that it will execute the multiple asynctask.

Now My Questions are that:

1. what is the problem to execute multiple asynctask parallelly.
2. why is the limit to execute only 138 asynctask at a time.
3. why does it differ with the android version.
4. what does it exactly means in kitkat to get number of processor currently running in VM and according that it will execute the asynctask.
5. what does asynctask use in background to track the waiting asynctask and Running Task.

Please Response For My Questions.

Comment: It's a phone, not a super computer. There needs to be a limit. If android allows your app to run x asynctasks in parallel, other apps would also take leverage of that and run their x asynctasks in parallel. It becomes cumbersome for the OS to manage so many threads. Hence there needs to be a limit. Every machine has a limit of fork. It can not create new threads beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class from Android developers

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

Internally the `AsyncTask` is implemented via an `Executor` and the default one is  `SerialExecutor`.

The the point of having a limit == number of CPU cores is that if the limit was bigger, than there'll be a constant race between the started threads. You know that end of the day you can have just  threads working at the same moment. In many cases this race between threads is not a problem, but in some it is. I guess Google just decided the pros are less than the cons and that's why they returned to `SerialExecutor` again. Again, quoting from `AsyncTask` class description:

> Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

These problems are mostly `InterruptedException` and `IllegalStateException`.

Lastly, if you really know what you're doing and have a solid reason to override Google's default behaviour you can do so by using `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executor, Object[])`, passing in a `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Comment: Realy Appreciate your answer @Vesko but I also just want to know from you that if once i have started a Async Task  can I stop it between the execution I tried it after calling cancel() method with Asynctask's object but it does not stop the thread execution, however in that case it  does not allow permit to call onPostExecute()  but doinBackground() method still does not stop its execution.

Comment: Yes, you can call myAsyncTask.cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning). Read the documentation of cancel() method to see how it works in details (it's not as intuitive as it sounds)

Comment: Hello @Vesko Can you tell me that who handle and track the multiple Async task in android means to keep them in blocking thread and give them permission to execute and so on in  Android System.